# Lucene 3: Where is StandardAnalyzer?

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on Lucene 3.x (source code). To start with I downloaded

1. latest source code from SVN
2. stable code 3.0.2 from: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/java/

The second one has source files for package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard, however the first one does not have any such files (not even the package). Somewhere in issue list I found StandardAnalyzer is deprecated from 3.x

Anyone, lucene developer here, enlighten me with reasons for such differences in source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like they are moving the StandardAnalyzer (and the related stuff) under org.apache.lucene.modules.analysis.standard.*

I don't know the reason though. You can find the StandardAnalyzer in the SVN Trunk here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/modules/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/

Comment: The reason is that Lucene and Solr's development efforts have merged, and as a result the common parts are being moved:
See here: http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2010/04/lucene-and-solr-development-merged.html

Comment: Link returns 404 - not found.